# lm-sensors does not show up cpu temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature, lm-sensors

I have an athlon 5370 CPU with Asrock AM1B-ITX board. How can I display CPU temperature with lm-sensors?

This is what it shows when I run "sensors" command in terminal:

```
    radeon-pci-0008
    Adapter: PCI adapter
    temp1:        +19.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

    nct6776-isa-0290
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Vcore:          +1.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
    in1:            +1.85 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
    AVCC:           +3.34 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
    +3.3V:          +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
    in4:            +0.74 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
    in5:            +1.69 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
    in6:            +0.70 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
    3VSB:           +3.44 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
    Vbat:           +3.28 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
    fan1:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan2:          3383 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan3:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan4:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan5:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    SYSTIN:         +44.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
    CPUTIN:         +47.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
    AUXTIN:         +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
    PCH_CHIP_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
    PCH_CPU_TEMP:    +0.0°C  
    PCH_MCH_TEMP:    +0.0°C  
    intrusion0:    ALARM
    intrusion1:    ALARM
    beep_enable:   disabled

    k10temp-pci-00c3
    Adapter: PCI adapter
    temp1:        +19.6°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                   (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +69.0°C)

    fam15h_power-pci-00c4
    Adapter: PCI adapter
    power1:           N/A  (crit =  24.96 W)
```

Can you help to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Did you do the `sensors-detect` command? See `man sensors-detect` for more information.

Comment: Yes I run that command first time after installation.